# App Store receipt validation: How to check if entire paid app was refunded (not in-app purchase)?

Tags: objective-c, macos, app-store, mac-app-store, receipt-validation

Suppose a customer bought my paid app in the Mac App Store, and then asked Apple and was issued a refund. Does Apple somehow invalidates the receipt to render the app impossible to use any longer? And if so, is there some kind of flag in the receipt that shows that it was refunded, that I should test during the receipt validation?

I found `cancellation_date` field ([Apple Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-RECEIPT-HOW_DO_I_USE_THE_CANCELLATION_DATE_FIELD_)) but it seems only for subscriptions or in-app purchases. How about refunding the whole paid app, is it examinable?

Seems like the answer used to be "no, Apple doesn't invalidate refunded Mac app receipts and the user can keep using the app", and I'd like to know if this has changed recently.

Comment: This thread was created over two years ago. I am also interested in finding a solution. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I haven’t found a positive answer to this question. It seems that this feature has not been implemented by Apple as of yet.

Comment: I did some research and it seems that it is indeed possible to detect a refunded app. You have to validate the receipt. It is not a trivial task but not impossible. See this link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/46737